# How to implement the following COUNTIF function into POWER BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I use a COUNTIF function to count and increment the number of instances of an ID in excel.

| Id_Treatment_Count | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 769334 |
| 1 | 769345 |
| 2 | 769345 |
| 1 | 769376 |
| 3 | 769345 |

In Excel, I would get the above using `=COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)` and then I would drag down (Id_treatment_count being column A and ID being column B).

How can I get the Id_treatment_Count in Power BI using DAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use EARLIER  refer to an earlier row context created by FILTER. It's a bit like saying for each row, count the number of rows including this one and any before it that have the same ID.(That's what I understood from what you provided) This gives you an incrementing count for each ID as you would get with the COUNTIF  in Excel :

```
  Id_Treatment_Count = 
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            'Table',
            'Table'[ID] = EARLIER('Table'[ID])
            && 'Table'[Index] <= EARLIER('Table'[Index])
        )
    )
```